# D3.js year scale shows different data for users in Europe and North America

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js

During the development of a website showing data for various indicators using D3.js, I experience a strange bug which I am unable to explain.

**How to recreate the issue**

1. Please visit the page at http://green-horizons.eu/indicator/scientific-publications-bioeconomy
2. Below the two text boxes there is a map with four buttons above it, please click on "Line Chart".
3. The map will be replaced by a line chart, showing a green line for Belgium's data and a red line for EU/ERA average values.
4. Now, please focus on the x axis which shows the years.

The x axis should cover the year range 1990-2013. This is true for all tests I and my colleagues did when in Europe (tested countries are Belgium, Estonia and Germany), see following image.

[image: Correct x axis (Europe)]

However, for anyone in the USA (and possibly Canada), the x axis shows a range of 1989-2012, see screenshot below (please note, the red line is missing due to only been added as a new feature recently).

[image: Incorrect x axis (USA)]

Internally, the data comes from uploaded CSV files which are parsed into JSON and then used in D3.js. For the date scale, all year values are expanded to make a full date by using sth like

```
dateValue = year + '-01-01';
```

The javascript object containing the data also shows the correct years for all users (even in the US) but the display is off by one year.

**How is this possible? I thought about time zones but I am not working with times, just dates.**
I even tried to set the date to first of June instead of January to be sure but still the same behaviour.

Can anyone point me into a direction what to look for, I am stuck and out of ideas of how to pinpoint the source of the error.

*Update regarding Mark's comment about the function*

```
// Determine year range.
var yearTicks = [];
for (var y = obj.chartYMin; y <= obj.chartYMax; y++) {
  yearTicks.push(new Date(y + "-01-01"));
}
// Set x scale function
var x = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([new Date((obj.chartYMin - 1) + "-01-01"), 
     d3.time.day.offset(new Date((obj.chartYMax + 1) + "-01-01"), 1)])
  .rangeRound([0, obj.width]);
// Create x axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
  .tickSize(-obj.height)
  .tickSubdivide(true)
  .tickValues(yearTicks)
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));
// Update x axis in graph.
d3.select("#scoreboard-" + obj.chartType + "-canvas .x.axis").call(xAxis);
```

obj.chartYMin and obj.chartYMax are the minimum and maximum year values in the data provided, yearTicks is an array of all years present in data.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you are using to create the scale ? I browsed to your website, but there's a wall of code there.

Comment: Thanks for looking, @Mark - I added (hopefully) the relevant code you were looking for.

Comment: Did you also try to apply your "june hack" to your calculation of the `yearTicks` array?

Comment: Yes indeed, I made sure by find&replace all occurrences of `-01-01` with `-06-01` but it didn't help. Still the same problem. This morning, I even got more confirmation mails from our transatlantic colleagues in the US, they all see the same `1989-2012` range instead of `1990-2013`.